# cannot assign a value to 64-bit integer on 32-bit platform

Tags: c, 64-bit, types, 32-bit, 32bit-64bit

After switching from 64-bit to 32-bit platform (both of them are CentOS) I get `integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type` error for the following line of code

```
uint64_t Key = 0x100000000;
```

Casting the value does not help. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make the integer constant of the right type.  The problem is that `0x100000000` is interpreted as an `int`, and casting / assignment doesn't help: the constant itself is too big for an `int`.  You need to be able to specify that the constant is of `uint64_t` type:

```
uint64_t Key = UINT64_C(0x100000000);
```

will do it.  If you don't have `UINT64_C` available, try:

```
uint64_t Key = 0x100000000ULL;
```

In fact, in C99 (6.4.4.1p5):

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

and the list for hexadecimal constants without any suffix is:

```
int
long int unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

So if you invoked your compiler in C99 mode, you should not get a warning (thanks Giles!).

Answer (score 4):

What you've written is perfectly valid C99 (assuming you've `#include`d `<stdint.h>`)¹. So it looks like you've invoked your compiler in C89 mode rather than C99 mode. In C89, there is no guarantee that a 64-bit type is available, but it's a common extension.

Since you're on Linux, your compiler is presumably gcc. Gcc supports a 64-bit `long long` on all platforms, even in C89 mode. But you may have to explicitly declare the constant as `long long`:

```
uint64_t Key = 0x100000000ull;
```

(`ll` means `long long`; `u` means unsigned and is optional here). Alternatively, you may want to run gcc in C99 mode with `gcc -std=c99`.

¹ <sub>for the language lawyers: and have an integral type with exactly 64 value bits.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No guarantee, but you might try:

```
uint64_t Key = 0x100000000ULL;
```